# Why are only consonants being played in my Android Text-To-Speech code?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

My code for TTS.

```
public void speakUp() {
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    Locale frenchLocale = new Locale("fr", "FR");
                    int result = tts.setLanguage(frenchLocale);
                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
                            result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("error", "This Language is not supported");
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                } else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR)
                    Log.e("error", "Initilization Failed!");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void ConvertTextToSpeech(String text, Float f) {
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        tts.setSpeechRate(f);
    }
```

The array I am playing:

```
private String[] names = {"A","B","C","D", "E", "F", "G", "H","ee", "J", "K","L","M","N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S","T","U","V","W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
```

for playing:

ConvertTextToSpeech(names[resID], 1.1f);

All other letters are playing except vowels. What issue is that? Does anyone know?

Comment: Try to replace the letters like this: "-A-" instead of "A". It probably has something to do with how Android TTS handles lone staying letters and probably varies from language to language. But my trick should work.

Comment: I tried with "-A-", not working.

Comment: Maybe I have to end up using recorded audio samples for the desired letter sounds instead of relying solely on TTS for individual letter pronunciation.

Comment: Did you try other languages?

Comment: Try to add spaces between the vocals like this: " A " instead of "A". Maybe you can also try to set a point like "A.".

Comment: yes its working with english and spanish. let me try spaces.

Comment: spaces did'nt worked with vowels as well.

Comment: Sorry to hear about that. I am curious about a solution too.

Comment: I finally used mp3 sounds as a solution.